# read data from list and create string to write flat file

Tags: java

I have rows of data in ArrayList. I need to read the data from List and convert it to  another format and write to flat file.

```
List Data:
General Details|S|!|!|66T4051|N|MACH|a
Charge Details|S|!|!|66T4051| 3827|N|
Charge Details|S|!|!|66T4051| 3828|N| 
Insurance Details|S|!|!|66T4051|   f|
Insurance Details|S|!|!|66T4051|   h|
Insurance Details|S|!|!|66T4051|   p|
```

Here GeneralDetails count is 1 and this is the master data. Charge Details count is 2. Insurance Details count is 3.

I need to transform the above list data in to one string in below format.

```
ROW1|General Details|S|!|!|66T4051|N|MACH|a|2|Charge Details|S|!|!|66T4051| 3827|N|Charge Details|S|!|!|66T4051| 3828|N|3|Insurance Details|S|!|!|66T4051|   f|Insurance Details|S|!|!|66T4051|  h|Insurance Details|S|!|!|66T4051|   p$
```

I need to place count before each record. lets say.

```
ROW1 - 1 is the count of General Details
|2|Charge Details - 2 is the count of Charge Details
|3|Insurance Details - 3 is the count of Insurance Details
```

please suggest how to achieve this?

i got the count for each row.

```
map>{Charge Details=2, General Details=1,Insurance Details=3}
```

but i m not able to proceed after that.

```
public void processRows(LinkedList<LinkedList<Object>> linkedList,String intfCode,String bankId)
{
for(int i=0;i<linkedList.size();i++)
{
   List<Object> list =  linkedList.get(i);
   //System.out.println("list>>"+i+""+list);

   List<Object> tableNameList =  new ArrayList<Object>();
   LinkedHashMap map = new LinkedHashMap();

   for(int j=0;j<list.size();j++)
   {
       String rowOfLine = (String)list.get(j);
       String split[] = (rowOfLine.split("\\|"));
       String tableName=split[0];
       tableNameList.add(tableName);
   }
   for(int j=0;j<list.size();j++)
   {
       String rowOfLine = (String)list.get(j);
       String split[] = (rowOfLine.split("\\|"));
       String tableName=split[0];

       int count = Collections.frequency(tableNameList, tableName);
       System.out.println("count>>"+count);
       if(!(map.containsKey(tableName)) && tableName!=null)
       {
       map.put(tableName, count);
       }
       //transformRow(tableName,intfCode,bankId,rowOfLine,collateralType);
   }
       System.out.println("map>"+map);


}
}
```

Comment: Please show some code and effort.

Comment: yes.i posted code which i tried.

Comment: Your map doesn't look like it has the correct counts for items based off of your example input...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code for your requirement.

Code:

import java.util.ArrayList;

```
public class Sample1 {

    public static void main( String[] str ) {
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add( "General Details|S|!|!|66T4051|N|MACH|a" );
        list.add( "Charge Details|S|!|!|66T4051| 3827|N|" );
        list.add( "Charge Details|S|!|!|66T4051| 3828|N|" );
        list.add( "Insurance Details|S|!|!|66T4051|   f|" );
        list.add( "Insurance Details|S|!|!|66T4051|   h|" );
        list.add( "Insurance Details|S|!|!|66T4051|   p|" );

        StringBuffer mainBuf = new StringBuffer();
        StringBuffer tempBuf = new StringBuffer();

        int count = 0;
        String header = null;
        for( String item : list ) {
            String[] values = item.split( "\\|" );

            // if this is first element
            if( header == null ) {
                header = values[0];
                count = 1;
            }
            // check if the previous element and present element is not same.
            else if(!header.equals(values[0])) {
                append( count, header, mainBuf, tempBuf.toString() );
                tempBuf.delete( 0, tempBuf.length() );
                count = 1;
                header = values[0];
            } else {
                count++;
            }
            if( tempBuf.length() > 0 && tempBuf.charAt( tempBuf.length() - 1 ) != '|' ) {
                tempBuf.append( "|" );
            }
            tempBuf.append( item );
        }
        append( count, header, mainBuf, tempBuf.toString() );

        // replace last character as $ 
        int lastIndex = mainBuf.length();
        mainBuf.replace( lastIndex - 1, lastIndex, "$" );
        System.out.println(" mainBuf => " + mainBuf );
    }

    public static void append( int count, String header, StringBuffer mainBuf, String str ) {
        if( header.equalsIgnoreCase(  "General Details" ) ) {
            mainBuf.append( "ROW" + count + "|" ).append( str );
        } else {
            if( mainBuf.charAt( mainBuf.length() - 1 ) != '|' ) {
                mainBuf.append( "|" );
            }
            mainBuf.append( count + "|" ).append( str );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through all the lists and pay attention to the right ordering of the lists.
Whenever a new list type begins append the number of lists to your String before iterating.

Answer (score 0):

`I have rows of data in ArrayList. I need to read the data from List and convert it to another format and write to flat file.`

Here is an idea of how you may solve your problem. Bear in mind that I have not tested this code my intent is to show you an idea of how you may solve your problem. Assuming that your `ArrayList` with data is named `contents` ...

```
Map<String, List<String>> indexedContents = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
for (String str : contents) {
    String[] splittedString = str.split("\\|");
    if (splittedString.length > 0) {
    //Index your map on the first entry which is something like
    //"Charge Details"
    if(indexedContents.get(splittedString[0]) == null){
        indexedContents.put(splittedString[0], new ArrayList<String>());
    }
    indexedContents.get(splittedString[0]).add(str);
    }
}
StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
for(String key : indexedContents.keySet()){
    output.append(indexedContents.get(key).size()).append("|");
    for(String values : indexedContents.get(key)){
    output.append(values).append("|");
    }
}
```

The entry in the map will keep track of your size since it's a `List`. The final for loop actually creates your output format which can be altered as you see fit. I hope that this helps.